# Different Definitions of Linear Functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question: Does the 1st definition agree with the 2nd definition and if not, what is the form of a linear function f:R→R?

1st Definition: In elementary algebra and calculus courses, it is often said that f:R→R is linear if and only if it has the form f(x)=ax+b, where a and b are constants.

2nd Definition: Another definition is that f:X→Y is linear if f(nx+my)=nf(x)+mf(y) for all scalar n,m and for all x,y that exist in X.

My work:

f(nx+my)=a(nx+my)+b

f(nx+my)=anx+amy+b

so the definitions do not agree. However, i dont know how to find the form of the linear function f:R→R. Thanks.

Comment: The second definition is the definition of a linear transformation, in the sense of linear algebra. It is indeed different from the first definition. Actually, you can check that the linear maps $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ according to the second definition all have the form $f(x)=ax$, which means we must have $b=0$ here. As for the first definition, I call such maps affine functions. (though if you study a topic which has nothing to do with linear transformations you might call such functions linear)

Comment: What has your question to do with `partial-differential-equations`?